# Wrong Chrome Extension submitted for review - how to stop?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

We accidentally submitted the wrong extension for review and don't see any way of cancelling it and re-submitting.

If this extension gets approved and subsequently pushed to our customers, it will 100% break.

There has to be a way to prevent this?

If we unpublish the extension, will it also stop the review and then allow us to re-submit it? Hopefully it won't come to this, but we need to stop this extension from being submitted/approved.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way to stop a review once submitted. What you can do is unpublished the extension and wait for the review to be complete. The new package wouldn't be available via the store so it will prevent browsers from auto-updating to the wrong extension.

After the review is complete you can then upload the correct extension and then republish after that review cycle has taken place.